# The cursor remains on TeXstudio after the Zotero picker window shows up

Tags: texstudio, zotero

I have a problem. I used this https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/comment/389917/#Comment_389917 to show up the Zotero picker window in front of TeXstudio. But when the Zotero picker window shows up, the cursor remains on TeXstudio. Consequently, I have to manually navigate to the Zotero picker using the mouse and click on it. Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: I'm not using Zotero, so I cannot really help. (I'm also not sure, if this is on-topic here, because it is a known issue already reported). So just two notes: 1. With Linux, the behavior could also depend on the settings of the window manager. 2. I would recommend to add a comment to the [reported issue](https://github.com/zotero/zotero-libreoffice-integration/issues/41) that it not restricted to LibreOffice.

Comment: Ok, I added to the reported issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by creating a Python file with the help of ChatGPT. The file brings the 'Quick Format Citation' window to the front based on its title. I incorporated this script into Texstudio and added a delay function to ensure proper execution. Additionally, I use an openApp.pyw script to open Zotero if it's closed. I hope this solution proves helpful to others.